# Python: moving to a new computer

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, installation

I'm moving from a computer with  windows xp  to one with windows 7 (64 bit) and I want to install Python on the new machine.  I'm currently using python 2.7 and 3.2 and a bunch of packages

1) Should I install the 64 bit versions?

2) How can I tell which packages I currently have, so that I can get those for the new machine?

If these are duplicates (my search skills seem to be failing), please point me to the threads where they're discussed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pip now for this purpose.

using `pip list` will give you a list of the packages that you have installed and the versions.

You could also use `pip freeze` and then copy the output of this to a file and then use this as a requirements files so you can install those exact modules and versions again on the new computer.
More information on pip is here is [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/)

but to install from a requirements files you would use

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Type `help('modules')` on the Python shell to get a list of all installed modules. If you can find stable 64-bit versions, then by all means select 64-bit builds for installations.

Answer (score 1):

From your Python home folder go to `../Lib/site-packages/` and save the folder listing to a file, e.g. `ls > ~/my-python-modules.txt` on Linux/OSX, or `dir > my-python-modules.txt` on Windows. The file will contain all the additional modules that have been installed on your system. Also, from the same folder search for `*.pth` files: they might contain the names of modules that were installed as Python Eggs.

On Linux/OSX the location of the `site-packages` folder might vary: use `locate -b site-packages` to quickly find out where they are.

To reinstall the modules it is best to use your system's built-in package manager if it has one (this will be the case if you use Linux or MacPorts), otherwise you will need to use `easy_install` (the package is called [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)) or `pip` ([url](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)). On Windows with modules that need C/C++ compilation it is easiest to use binary executable installers, unless you have a sane build environment like MS Visual Studio  or MinGW. If you install binary packages then it is probably best to get the 64-bit version to match your architecture. Not sure if 32 bit versions will work or will event install.